# Finding the max voltage on a pnp transistor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

I hope you are having a lovely day. I have a quick question about the following circuit.
I am trying to determine what Vx should be equal to in order for this circuit to supply 8 mA to a 250 Ohm load. I'm letting Ve be a node right after the 4.5V source and Vc be the node right after the pop transistor.
Here is my attempt to solve so far:

Vr = 250 Ohm * 0.08 A = 20 V.

Vec =4.5 - 0 = 4.5V - (400*0.08) - (1*0.08)*100e3 ohm - Vx - Vr

Therefore, (400*0.08) - (1*0.08)*100e3 ohm - Vx - Vr = 4.5

32 - 8000 - Vx - 20 = 4.5

-7988 -Vx = 4.5

Vx = -7983.5 ??

which just makes no sense at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!!

[image]

Comment: 8mA = 0.008A may help a little

Comment: Then work from the top - the 100R resistor must pass 401/400 * 8mA, so work out the voltage drop across it, then add the Vbe drop in the transistor.  That gives you the voltage at the base, and then work out the voltage you'll need in the 100k resistor to achieve the required base current (8mA/400).